# How to add GPS metadata to TIFF in Java?

Tags: java, gps, metadata, tiff, jai

I am attempting to add GPS data to a TIFF file I am creating in Java.  I am using the JAI-ImageIO libraries, although if there is a better library for doing both GPS metadata and custom metadata, I am willing to look into it.

I have attempted to add the GPS metadata to the nodes directly, but it seems to strip off the GPS IDF tag.  I have attempted to add the GPS IFD to the TIFFIFD object (from the TIFFIMageMetadata object), but that doesn't seem to save the data properly.

Basically, I am struggling to get it to save the GPS data properly, and trying to figure out how to get the data in there.  Hours of searching on the internet have yielded little in the way of tutorials or help, and I don't see anything helpful on Stack Overflow, but my search abilities may be lacking.

Some code from my attempt at doing it by manipulating the metadata nodes directly:

```
RenderedImage img = generateImageSomehow();
File writeTarget = new File("blah.tiff");
//Get the image writer
Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tiff");
ImageTypeSpecifier specifier = new ImageTypeSpecifier(renderedImage);
ImageWriter writer = writers.next();
//Get the metadata
IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(specifier, writers.getDefaultWriteParam());
Node root = metadata.getAsTree(FileConstants.TIFF_METADATA_FORMAT);
Node ifd = root.getFirstChild();
//Create a new IFD node for the GPS data, and add some GPS data to it
IIOMetadataNode gpsRootNode = new IIOMetadataNode("TIFFIFD");
gpsRootNode.setAttribute(FileConstants.TIFF_FIELD_NUMBER_ATTRIBUTE, "34853");
gpsRootNode.setAttribute(FileConstants.TIFF_FIELD_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, "GPS");
gpsRootNode.setAttribute("tagSets", "com.sun.media.imageio.plugins.tiff.EXIFGPSTagSet");
IIOMetadataNode childNode = new IIOMetadataNode(FileConstants.TIFF_FIELD_TAG);
childNode.setAttribute(FileConstants.TIFF_FIELD_NUMBER_ATTRIBUTE, "1");
childNode.setAttribute(FileConstants.TIFF_FIELD_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, "GPSLatitudeRef");
IIOMetadataNode asciiNode = new IIOMetadataNode("TIFFAsciis");
IIOMetadataNode childAsciiNode = new IIOMetadataNode("TIFFAscii");
childAsciiNode.setAttribute(FileConstants.TIFF_FIELD_VALUE_ATTRIBUTE, "N");
asciiNode.appendChild(childAsciiNode);
childNode.appendChild(asciiNode);
gpsRootNode.appendChild(childNode);
ifd.appendChild(gpsRootNode);
//Update metadata with new tree
metadata.setFromTree(FileConstants.TIFF_METADATA_FORMAT, root);
ImageOutputStream outstr = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(writeTarget);
writer.setOutput(outstr);
//Write the image
IIOImage img = new IIOImage(renderedImage, Collections.<BufferedImage> emptyList(), metadata);
writer.write(img);
outstr.close();
```

I am attempting to join the GPS root node in, along with a (currently hardcoded) value for the direction.  Am I attaching at the wrong level, in the wrong place, in the wrong way, etc?  I am fine doing it this way - although using the TIFF objects might be nicer.

Updated to add additional code, to show how I am creating the image, as well as how I am saving it.

---

ETA:

This line here:

```
ifd.appendChild(gpsRootNode);
```

Should actually be:

```
root.appendChild(gpsRootNode);
```

This was something I was trying out, but when I do the ifd node as the node where I add the GPS node, I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFIFD cannot be cast to [J
```

Not sure if that is expected there - it looks like it is trying to cast the IFD node to a Long array (as per the standard JNI types) - when I attach it to the root, it just seems to remove it from the metadata nodes.

Comment: Is `TIFF_METADATA_FORMAT` "com_sun_media_imageio_plugins_tiff_image_1.0" or something else?

Comment: It is that text - I copied that from the getMetadataFormats() function.

Comment: Hmmm.. It seems there are some issues with the metadata structure. The `TIFFIFD` tag is defined (in the DTD) to have attributes `"parentTagNumber"` and `"parentTagName"`, not `"number"` and `"name"`. Note that the names are all redundant, I'd avoid them in the code, to make it less verbose. Also, I think `gpsRootNode` should be a child of `ifd` (like in the code), not `root` as in your edit. It's a sub-IFD, not the IFD of the second image.

Comment: @haraldK Looking into Sanselan - looks like I might be able to do what I need.  I will let you know.  Thanks again for all of your help - it is most appreciated! :)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe) is a Java image library which can insert EXIF, GPS data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the metadata tree representation you are manipulating, is only a working copy. When you later write an image and pass it `metadata`, your changes to the tree representation are lost.

After you are done updating the metadata tree (`root`) with your GPS specific tags, you have to either call [`metadata.setFromTree(TIFF_METADATA_FORMAT, root)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata.html#setFromTree%28java.lang.String,%20org.w3c.dom.Node%29) or [`metadata.mergeTree(TIFF_METADATA_FORMAT, root)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata.html#mergeTree%28java.lang.String,%20org.w3c.dom.Node%29) to set/merge your changes back to the `metadata` instance. As you start out with `metadata.getAsTree(..)` rather than an empty structure, you probably want to use `setFromTree(..)`.

PS: If this is not the problem, please add the code where you update your metadata and write the image. :-)

Comment: That is not the problem, because I am doing that after this code is finished - I will add it tonight when I get home (this is a contract project, not part of my day job) - I just forgot to add it in to the original post.

Comment: @aperkins Ok. Do that. Or better yet, write an SSCCE. :-) I'll delete the answer then.

Comment: Updated the question with the writing portion (and metadata saving portion).  I can attempt to get an SSSCCE, but the problem is the data I am working with is confidential, so I can't really include that.  Basically, we have a set of image data that we are saving, and any other changes I make to the metadata save fine, but if I add a GPS IFD to it, it just trims it off.  This includes other, custom nodes (as defined in the EXIF spec)

Comment: Also, if there is a better way to do this - to modify/append additional metadata to TIFFs (or to the app1 segment of compressed images) that uses different APIs, libraries, etc - I would love to do it that way instead.  There just seems to be very, very little information about it at this stage.

Comment: @aperkins I don't think it matters for the SSCCE that you use dummy data, as long as you can show the problem.

Comment: OK - I will try and get something tonight (I am in the States, so it will be a while from when I post this)  Thanks for keeping with me on this - I am pretty frustrated at this point, haven't had a problem this bad in a while :P

Comment: @aperkins Good. I'm working on a TIFF reader/writer plugin that should possibly be able to replace the JAI version at some point, so I have some self-interest in this as well.. ;-) Anyway. I think maybe Sanselan/Apache Commons Imaging could help. The ImageIO metadata part is a little over-engineered IMO.

Comment: It didn't look like it supported extensions - using the "open" range in the TIFFs for custom metadata.  Am I wrong on that?

Comment: @aperkins Sorry, I have limited experience with Sanselan/Commons imaging, it just sounded like a possible fit.